# MVC 6 - Getting 404 error on IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is all I get

> Status Code: 404; Not Found

Here is the environment.

- IIS 7.5
- Windows 2008 R2
- ASP.NET 5 RC and HttpPlatformHandler are installed.

...and what I've done.

1) Checked the log directory that stdoutLogFile in the web.config points to. Don't see any errors. Just a lot of these:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET <websiteName>
```

2) RDP in and can browse to the site after running web.cmd in the approot directory. Site runs fine that way. Can not access it with IIS.

3) Startup.cs/configure contains

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
```

4) Local publish. Copy to server. Website points to wwwroot directory. Approot sits next to it.

5) processPath points to "..\approot\web.cmd".

6) Published with DNX version dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1. Also tried the same 64 bit version.

7) HttpPlatformHandler  is installed.

8) Checked the IIS error logs and didn't see anything interesting.

What should I try next?

Update

I have these environment variables mapped.

```
DNX_HOME - C:\Users\<user>\.dnx
DNX_PACKAGES - C:\Users\<user>\.dnx\packages
DNX_PATH - C:\Users\<user>\.dnx\bin\dnvm.cmd
```

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 is installed.

Comment: To what URL are you navigating when you receive the 404?

Comment: Open project properties. Select tab Web. Change 'Current Page' to 'Specific Page'. Textbox leave empty.

Comment: @Shaun Luttin, I get the 404 with any URL. Tried it with many variations including only the hostname and variations of controllers and indexes. Nothing  worked.

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov, I don't have a tab 'web' in my project properties. I have Application, Build and Debug. In the Debug tab I set it to web and published. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Recycle the application pool each time you do a troubleshooting step.

2) Try a vastly simplified application. If you still receive a 404, then we know something is up with the hosting not with the application.

The following super-simple application is working for us in IIS.

**C:/App00/Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;

namespace App00
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from RC1!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**C:/App00/project.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {}
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
    }
}
```

**C:/App00/wwwroot/web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" 
           modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" 
         stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Restore and Publish**

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -runtime clr
dnu restore
dnu publish --runtime active
```

**IIS Configuration**

```
Physical Path     C:\App00\bin\output\wwwroot
```

Comment: Thanks! There is a problem with my application.

Comment: Good stuff... thank you for marking as answer. Could you also please mark the upvote. :)

Comment: Are you using sub applications in IIS? They mess up MVCs routing: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/14

Comment: I know it's been a while but have you solved it? I replaced my Configure-method with yours and it worked so I think there's something wrong with MVC Routing. I don't use sub applications and virtual directories in iis.

Comment: @FRules The original poster marked the answer as correct, so I assume that the answer solved his question.